# IBM MQ: DISPLAY CHANNEL command - syntax error

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to Display IBM MQ channels using

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086040_.htm

I defined a channel named `MYMQ.SVRCONN`, however, this gives me a syntax error:

```
runmqsc
DISPLAY CHANNEL MYMQ.SVRCONN
 5 : DISPLAY CHANNEL MYMQ.SVRCONN
```

AMQ8405: Syntax error detected at or near end of command segment below:-
DISPLAY CHANNEL

I get the same problem with:

```
DISPLAY CHANNEL *
```

Any suggestions why?

I'm struggling to understand this syntax:

```
>>-DISPLAY CHANNEL--(--generic-channel-name--)------------------>
```

so bonus points if you can explain how syntax works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(` and `)` are part of the required syntax.

In the examples you give the commands should be:

```
DISPLAY CHANNEL(MYMQ.SVRCONN)
```

or

```
DISPLAY CHANNEL(*)
```

Most MQSC command have a similar syntax of:

```
<command> <object type>(<object name>) [optional parameters]
```

A few examples:

1. `DEFINE CHL(MYMQ.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('xyzuser')`
2. `ALTER CHL(MYMQ.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) DESCR('Test channel')`
3. `DISPLAY CHL(MYMQ.SVRCONN) MCAUSER`

The `QMGR` object is one of the exceptions where the object type does not need to be followed by a object name since when you run these commands you are connected to a specific queue manager:

1. `DIS QMGR CHLAUTH CONNAUTH`
2. `ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(ENABLED)`

A few things to note:

1. IBM MQ will always fold to UPPER case anything that is not surrounded in single quote `'` characters.
2. Some `DISPLAY` commands by default display only a subset of all parameters on an object.  You can use the special parameter `ALL` to have it display all of them or you can indicate specific parameters you would like to display.
3. `DISPLAY` commands can also use a `WHERE` clause, for example: `DIS CHL(*) WHERE(MCAUSER eq 'xyzuser') DESCR`